# Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Tags: php, html, email

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['send'])){
        if(isset($_POST['email']) != ""){
            if(isset($_POST['Topic']) != ""){
                if(isset($_POST['text']) != ""){
                    $comment                = $_POST['text'];
                    $email                       = $_POST['email'];
                    $Topic                       = $_POST['Topic'];

                    mail($email, $Topic, $comment);
                }
            }
        }
    }

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MAIL</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form action = "mail.php" method = "post">
      <input type = "text" name = "Topic">
       <input type = "text" name = "text" required = "required">
       <input type = "email" name = "email" required>
       <input type = "submit" name = "send">

   </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Менял порт не помогло что делать?

Comment: Поставьте OpenServer, который уже настроен и сохраняет mail-письма в отдельном какталоге.

Comment: И, кстати, почитайте про isset() — она возвращает только false или true. Поэтому ваши if составлены некорректно.

Comment: я работаю с XAMPP и он у меня настроен но идет сбой 25 порта

Comment: Нужен сервер почты. Вряд ли он есть на localhost'е.